# How to understand Register Address, Bits, and Reset value of an electronic component?

Tags: memory, register

[image: Table of ADXL355 MEMS' RESET value]

Source: [Page 31 ADXL355 MEMS' Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl354_adxl355.pdf).

[image: Status Register's bit breakdown]

Source: [Page 32 ADXL355 MEMS' Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl354_adxl355.pdf)

The above is some of ADXL355 Accelerometer Register map table. From that table, in the RESET column, there are their respective value. There are 48 register addresses, from ***0x00*** - ***0x2F***. Mostly the reset values are ***0x00***, but there are some that are not, they are: ***0xAD, 0x1D, 0xED, 0x01, 0x60, 0x81***. POWER_CTL itself, as written in that page I screenshot, has ***0x01*** its reset value.

The second picture shows a breakdown of the STATUS Register. As we may see, bit [4:0] have their own bit name, function, reset value, and access status, while bit [5-7] are reserved. The rest are broke down according to their function or need. The detail is in that datasheet.

So here, what I want to ask are:

1. What is that register address?
2. What is that bits value? What is their relation to register address and reset value, and how that bits themselves have their own reset value apart from the register [address] reset value?
3. Still related to (especially) that STATUS register, what should be the value of those bits [4:0]? There is no explanation in that datasheet either they are 0 or 1 to show their function as in their description.
4. What is the purpose of that so called RESERVED bits in every register?
5. What is that reset value, why do they are different?
6. How to link them all to give a comprehensive understanding?

*Note:*

I am struggling to understand this register so I could have missed some key point here, or maybe some consider this trivial, but I do I am struggling to understand. So, if one knows well about it, kindly edit this post so it is clearer.

Answer (score 4):

A register is similar to a memory location or a variable. It can store a certain value which can usually be read or written. The register *address* is therefore similar to a memory address and is required if the device has more than one register (most devices do). When you write a register, you have to first transmit the register address and then the data you want to put into that register. If you want to read it, you first transmit the register address and then read from the bus (I2C in this case) to get the value of that register.

Setting a value to a register usually directly affects what the chip is doing, so it can be controlled this way. In this particular case many registers are read-only (as indicated by the "R" in the "R/W" or "Access" column), which means that they can only be read, writing to the registers will not do anything.

If you read out the status register, you get various information encoded in different bits. If you want to know whether the FIFO is full, you read that register and then check whether bit 1 is set. If so, that condition is true.

Reserved bits are, as the name calls, reserved by the manufacturer. They have no documented meaning and should never be interpreted in any way. When you read the register, you should just filter them out (e.g. by ANDing the value with 0x1F here). Reserved bits should normally also not be written to anything but their default values (if that's possible), as it may have undesirable effects, such as setting the chip to a test mode or something.

In your case, registers 0-0x03 are read-only, and thus their reset value is a constant and can be used to identify the chip and its revision. For other registers that are not read-only but have a non-zero default value that is just how the chip initializes itself.

Comment: They're not all read-only, that table has been cropped from the datasheet.

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks for pointing that out, in fact, the registers 0-0x11 (shown above) are all read only. Others are not.

Comment: @PMF, from address 1E-2E are R/W for any reset value. Looks like you are not good enough to answer my questions. There are lot of that my questions.

Comment: @PMF, Register indeed is a memory, NOT "similar to a memory location or a variable". It is a memory. To be more specific, it is storage, used to store things. In computer world, it is used to store any value or variable.

Comment: @AirCraftLover If you know the answer, why are you asking, then? And no, a register is not the same as memory, as it is usually implemented differently in hardware.

Comment: I have listed 6 my questions but your answer is like a science fiction script.

Comment: Your questions are all related, thus I have tried to give you the big picture, so that you hopefully understand what this is all about. If you've still not understood something, please ask a narrower question.

Comment: @AirCraftLover Try asking a more specific question. Nobody's going to write a complete textbook on how to use this device just for you.

Comment: @AirCraftLover - I think Finbarr has done a adequate job of answering your questions.  FWIW, the answers to all your questions is contained in the data sheet, and most of them are in the screenshots you provided.  For instance "that register address" is 0x04.

Comment: @SteveSh, What is the answer to the question 2-4?

Comment: @AirCraftLover PMF has answered those questions, although "what should be the value of those bits" is a bit meaningless as each one shows the status of part of the circuit and they will change according to what it's doing.

Comment: @Finbarr, if you said that one of you have answered my questions, then I can say that you know nothing about register and clearly, you never wrote any header file by reading datasheet.

Comment: @AirCraftLover Wrong on both counts, and you're not going to get answers by throwing insults.

Comment: Yep, @PMF has correctly answered your questions. Not only have I written scripts to automate the generation of register header files, but I've written data sheets and created registers for many devices. Plus 1 to PMF for the harassment after taking the time to write an accurate and complete answer.